# How to change site name of the nextjs 13 app directory website?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, metadata, vercel

[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZMiM.jpg)

I add this website on the google search results
But its site name shows **Vercel**

How to change site name to **DailyLearn**

```
const structuredData = {
  "@context": "https:schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  name: "DailyLearn",
  alternateName: ["DailyLearn", "Daily learn", "Dibrugarh university"],
  url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: JSON.stringify(structuredData),
        }}
      />
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

I want add structure data on head tag

Comment: Have you tried using Metadata? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) to define the title or other details about your page or website.

```js
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
 
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: '...',
  description: '...',
}
 
export default function Page() {}
```

Comment: I want to add structuredData on head tag